# Grouped boxplots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

This is my first time posting, so I hope I'm explaining the problem sufficiently.

I'm trying to create a grouped boxplot.

The dataframe I am using is massive (28000 obs of 3 variables) and essentially looks like this:

Label Variable    Value 
Agarose        5 124200.0 
Agarose        5 108664.0 
Agarose        5 126722.0 
Agarose        5 130785.0 
Agarose        5 121186.0 
Agarose        5 123460.0 
Agarose        5 120846.0 
Agarose        5 120843.0 
Agarose        5 166952.0 
Agarose        5 140078.0 
Agarose        5 128535.0 
Agarose        5 125572

etc, with 2 different labels (Agarose and LapAg) and 7 Variables (5,6,7,8,9,10,11).

I have tried several methods e.g.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=Variable, y=Value)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Label))

ggplot(aes(x=Variable,y=Value, fill=factor(Label))) +
  geom_boxplot() + labs(fill = "Label")
```

but each time it gives me this outcome:

[image: see plot here]

It seems to have bulked the data together, when I want it to show the 'labels' side by side of each variable, similar to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/307/bernd-weiss)

I'm not sure why this strange outcome keeps occuring - any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Apologies, the link to what I want the boxplot to look like doesn't work - https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/265-grouped-boxplot-with-ggplot2.html shows the type of grouped boxplot I'm after

Comment: Try with converting `Variable` to a factor, e.g. `ggplot(.., aes(x=factor(Variable), ...)`